# How to run Locust task n times

Tags: performance-testing, locust

Want to run nested Locust task n iterations in every sequential task set.
The only way that I've found for Locust 1.x versions is to multiply task in tasks:

```
class TaskA(SequentialTaskSet):
    ...
class TaskB(SequentialTaskSet):
     n = 5
     tasks = [TaskA for _ in range(n)]
```

What is the better and more correct way to run TaskA n times?
Options 1 & 2 below don't work in 1.3.1:

1:

```
class TaskB(SequentialTaskSet):    
    for _ in range(n):
        tasks = [TaskA]
```

2:

```
class TaskB(TaskSet):    
    for _ in range(n):
        tasks = {TaskA: n}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the answer to

**How do I do X with a SequentialTaskSet?**

is

**Don't use a SequentialTaskSet, just use Python!**

Can you achieve the same thing with a regular for loop & functions?

`tasks = [TaskA for _ in range(n)]` seems ok though, unless it doesnt do what you want it to?

Comment: It works ok, the only concern is possible extra memory usage if "n" is a big number.

Comment: Perhaps a for loop (inside the task, and not using SequentialTaskSet at all) is a better fit then?